# Connect to Android device from PC

Tags: javascript, android

I have an Android device connected to a PC via USB.

The Android device is not connected to the network.

Is it possible to communicate between the Android device and a javascript web application running on internet explorer on the PC?

[image]

requirements:

- We need to avoid installing anything new on the PCs, hunderds of PC are already deployed.
- The Android devices are not deployed yet, we are free to add anything.
- The WebApp will be running on Internet explorer, as per client's requirements.

I thought about using javascript web sockets on my web app on internet explorer (on PC) to listen to any incoming connection from the device, and then in my android app connect to that port and keeping the connection alive.

Is this possible? Are there other ways to do so?

Comment: That's a beautiful picture.  I am a little lost when you say u have a webapp running on IE.   I presume you mean Internet explorer.  From what I know, a webapp is a client-server app running in a web server, the client is a browser.  So I'm confused by the question.  If you want to connect with a different client you can, any browser other than IE on the device should work, and there are many android browsers available.

Comment: Well basically i have some android devices i need to reach from my server. The android devices are connected to the PC via USB and not to the network. So i am thinking of proxying the connection to the server through some javascript running on the PC. Thank you for the reply and please let me know if the questions is still ambiguous.

Comment: I see.  I noticed the USB symbol but was not certain you meant USB.  You did.  That's a good question.  Maybe this can help: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable

Comment: another: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1004745/  If you can use the internet connection of the PC using one of the techniques I linked to, then any browser on the device should be able to connect to the webapp the same way that IE does on the PC.

Comment: Yep that’s almost exactly my problem. The main difference is I should avoid installing android sdk on the hundreds of PCs the users have. The other difference is that i dob’t need to connect to the internet, just be able to talk to my server in both ways. The only solution i can think of is a socket connection between the javascript (pc) and the android app. Not sure that i still need installing android sdk on the computer for that though.

Comment: Your second link does not ask for anything to be installed on the PC (only some settings to adjust). I need to give that a try and see if i can in this case connect to the internet directly, if this option is available. Thank you.

Comment: YW.  In order to connect over USB using a socket or other, you'd probably need something built into android such as the USB tethering option described in that link.

Comment: With ADB debugging enabled, you could use [webadb](https://github.com/webadb/webadb.js) - but it depends on [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/), which is currently not implemented in browsers other than Chrome.